# idea doesn't build after git reset hard

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, build

Help me please.
After I had run command from console in Idea:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

I had problem with dependency in my project.
I can succesfully run next for project from console in Idea:

```
mvn clean install
```

but when I'm trying to do Build->Build Project in Idea there is the Error:(3, 1) java: package com.xxxxx.xx.xxxxx does not exist. I tried to execute maven -> reimport whole project and only this module, but it cannot help.

[image]

Comment: Try to delete `.idea` directory and reimport the project from `pom.xml`.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, Thank you very much